# pip stopped working after update to 20.1.1

Tags: python, pip

I always install packages with the command "python -m pip install " in cmd. Today I got the notification that I am using pip  and pip 20.1.1 can be installed by typing "python -m pip install --upgrade pip". I did that and now pip fails to install or uninstall programmes. This is the error message I get when trying to install a new package.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'webencodings' from 'pip._vendor' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\__init__.py)
```

I am a complete beginner and don't want to mess to much with the pip directory, is there an easy solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been happening with pip 20+ when your "system" pip install gets incorrectly upgraded -- it's honestly pretty messed up that the default upgrade command that pip itself *tells* you to use does this "wrong" upgrade.

See [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599) for a detailed discussion, a bunch of related issues, and some workarounds. [This more recent report](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599) has a bunch of people reporting the same for pip20.

Potentially the [easiest solution](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599#issuecomment-414157896) is to uninstall it:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
```

Which should bring you back to the "system" pip installation. And then just ignore the warning, or only work inside virtualenvs, where you shuold be able to safely use updated pip.

[Another possible workaround](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7620#issuecomment-576655739) is to install an older version manually using the get-pip script:

```
python get-pip.py pip==19.3.1
```

Note: If anyone has better advice please feel free to comment / correct me.